# Using dataset and show on Bing map

Tags: windows-phone-7, dictionary, bing

I want to program an application based on wpf c# language.

I've got the bing map running and i want the dataset to display on the map with pushpin on top of the specific locations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you could make it work but i could do this whit this few lines of XAML code and Binding.

```
<bing:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LocationsList}">
                    <bing:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <bing:Pushpin Location="{Binding Location}" Content="{Binding Content}">                                    
                            </bing:Pushpin>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </bing:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </bing:MapItemsControl>
```